# Cropping images in matlab for loop

Tags: matlab, image-processing, crop

I am trying to cut some images in a matlab for-loop. However, I am facing some problems in order to do so.  My code is the above:

```
clear
clc

dir
dir 'D:\christos\DATABASE\animal';
listing = dir('D:\christos\DATABASE\animal');

[m n] =  size(listing);

for indx=3:m
 listing(indx).name
 A = imread(strcat( 'D:\christos\DATABASE\animal\' , listing(indx).name)); 
 [t1 t2] = size(A); imshow(A);
 A = imcrop(A, [ (1/3)*t1 (1/3)*t2  (2/3)*t1 (2/3)*t2 ] );
 %A =  imresize(A, [360, 280]);
 imwrite(A, strcat('D:\christos\DAt\animal\animal_',  int2str(indx-2) , '.jpg'));
end
```

In some images, it doesnt work proper the imcrop line. Beside the fact that the images is been read and has size t1 t2, I cant cropped it in the way I want and I get as a result an empty A image.

Comment: What is the way you want to crop it then? Could you state your desired result, please?

Comment: Yea drom 1/3x_max to 2/3x_max and 1/3y_max 2/3y_max.

Comment: A general advice: give a different names to variables in your code. If you write `A=imcrop(A,...)`, you can't know if the problem of the empty matrix accures while reading the image, or while cropping it...

Comment: Another way to solve this is to use command line calls to ImageMagick, either via a batch script or via Matlab. It might be faster if you are operating on a lot of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some are colored images, so use this -

> [t1 t2 t3] = size(A);

and keep the rest of the code as it is.

With your original code for colored images, t2 would store - widthx3 and not the width itself.

Comment: No the actual problem was that I had opposite the t1 and t2.

Comment: Yes, it's the way MATLAB stores size information, can be confusing at times. But in any case, [t1 t2 t3] = size(A); is a safer way to stay out of troubles.